# Explanation on this code with delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

I read quite some articles about delegates, and yes, at first the syntax is confusing. I found *[this article the most useful.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/delegate)* **Example 2** makes it quite understandable how to use delegates. But I have this code given to me and have work with it:

```
public delegate bool IntPredicate(int x);
public delegate void IntAction(int x);

class IntList : List<int>
{
    public IntList(params int[] elements) : base(elements)
    {

    }

    public void Act(IntAction f)
    {
        foreach (int i in this)
        {
            f(i);
        }
    }
    public IntList Filter(IntPredicate p)
    {
        IntList res = new IntList();
        foreach (int i in this)
            if (p(i))
                res.Add(i);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Now, what confuses me here is the `f` and `p` variables in the `Act` and `Filter` functions. As in the tutorial, those functions seem to be normal, with normal type of their attributes, but here the attributes are of the delegate functions type and I get confusled.

Can you please enlighten me a bit on this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A delegate is just a type. With the types you're used to (like `int`, `string` etc.), when you want to use them, you either use one that is in the framework or you declare your own. You can do exactly the same with delegates - either use a prebuilt one (like `System.Action`) or declare your own, which is what was done here.

So, in your code snippet, 3 types are declared:

```
public delegate bool IntPredicate(int x);
public delegate void IntAction(int x);

class IntList : List<int> { ... }
```

You'll notice that the delegate declarations are on the same level as the class declaration.

When you have a type (like your `IntPredicate` here), you can then use it for variables or function parameters. The questions now are: how do you set the value of the variable, and what do you do with it then?

With ordinary variables, you just pass in the value. Like this:

```
string text = "Hello world";
```

The principle is the same with delegates, but, of course, you have to pass in something that is of the delegate type or something that can be converted to it. You have several options:

**Existing method**

You can pass in a method, if its signature (that is, the return value and parameters) match those of the delegate. So, you could do this:

```
void WriteIntAction(int value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}

/* then, in some other method */
IntList intList = new IntList(1,2,3);
intList.Act(WriteIntAction);
```

**Anonymous method**

There are several ways to create an anonymous method. I'm going to go with lambda expression, because that is simplest. If you've ever worked with any functional languages, this should be familiar.

```
IntList intList = new IntList(1,2,3);
intList.Act(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

So, after you have your variable set up with the method you need (whether existing or anonymous), you can simply use the delegate variable as you would any method. This is what this line does:

```
f(i);
```

Just be aware that delegate is a reference type, so the value of `f` here can be `null`, which will then throw an exception when you try to call a delegate.

**TL;DR**

A delegate is a type. You can use it in a variable or method parameter. You can pass a method in just using its name or you can create an anonymous method. You can then call the method you passed it by using the variable as you would a method.

You can read more online, for example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx

Comment: +1 really good explanation, couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks a lot! I just want to get one thing straight, to see if I understood correctly: in the scope of `Act` and `Filter`, the functions `f(i)` and `p(i)` are functions that I pass as arguments to `Act` and `Filter` and I decide what do they do by creating their bodies (i.e. in the `Main` function of the class)?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I think you understand correctly. The important thing is that the methods `Act` and `Filter` don't care what exactly the function you pass in does - they just execute it. Just like a `foreach` doesn't care what you do with the items you're enumerating.

Answer (score 1):

A delegate type is, for all intents and purposes, just a function (or if you are a C++ user, akin to a *function-pointer*). In other words, you call them just as if they were a function, which is exactly what the sample code does.

`f(i)` calls the passed function with the `i` variable as its sole argument, just as it looks.